# Angular/Firebase token/UUID for specific routes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on an Angular/Firebase app, that is supposed to have a public and a private parts. Specifically the private is an editor which manages and compiles personalized lists and the public part displays the lists to the end user. The Idea is to compile a list, generate a url, something like `lists/public/{id}` (where id is the id of the list), and then send this url to the person this list was created for, so only a person with this url can access it.

My current solution is to generate the UUID, and save it in the Firestore with the list, so that I can just query for it. The problem is that, I first need to send a query (give list where id == urlId) to Firestore, which I want to avoid.

My question is: Is there a more "dedicated" way of doing it with Firebase? And by 'it' I mean - creating and saving tokens in Firebase for accessing specific data in Firestore, without having to actually query it in the first place and without having to authenticate yourself first.

EDIT: By `I first need to send a query (give list where id == urlId)` I mean that in order to find a list for a specific URL, I first need to make a query to the Firestore which looks if the UUID in the generated url (form: `lists/public/{id}`) is present in the Firestore (a.i. a list with this UIID exists).
In code it would look like that:

```
const urlID = (some code that gets the id from URL)

const lists = collection(this.firestore, "lists");

const q = query(lists, where("UUID", "==", `${urldID}`));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I first need to send a query (give list where id == urlId) to Firestore, which I want to avoid."  Could you edit the question to be more clear about what you see is the problem with this? It might help to show actual code or psudocode to illustrate this procedure and where it will go wrong.

Comment: I still don't really understand what the problem is with what you're expressing.  Yes, you will make a query for documents that you need to read.  Why is that causing concern?  Why are you expecting there to be some alternative?  Is it cost?  Performance? Too many lines of code? What specifically are you looking for in an alternative? Please edit the question be clear what the problem is and what sort of solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure what's being asked here, but this answers my interpretation:

You don't need to make a query if you know exactly where the data is located. Within the collection, simply make the id **of the document itself** be the UUID.

So your lists collection would look something like:

```
lists ->
    // first document
    69df43ca-e868-11ec-8fea-0242ac120002: {
       "data": "foo"
    }
    // second document
    8f040e92-e868-11ec-8fea-0242ac120002: {
       "data": "bar"
    }
```

And the code to access an individual document would look like:

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const urlID = (some code that gets the id from URL)

// make a reference to the lists collection, with the "urlID" document
const documentRef = doc(db, 'lists', urlID);
const documentSnap = await getDoc(document);

// at which point you can check if it exists or doesn't exist
```

And then you can set up your firestore access rules so that documents in the lists collection can be read anonymously, but only written with authentication. And make sure to use a cryptographically secure UUID (unguessable), and don't allow users to list the contents of the "lists" collection, only read documents when they know the document id.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks, you understood my question correctly